# Can't take jar from artifactory

Tags: build.gradle, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have a jar file in the Artifactory which I published.
Now I want to take that jar file to build my code in the gradle script.

I have jars in the "`commonlibs-snapshot-local/UTIL/UTIL-2.jar`" path.
In the URL I am giving this path as "url of artifactory/commonlib-snapshot-local/".
In the dependencies section I'm giving like

```
dependencies {
    compile " UTIL/UTIL-2.jar"
}
```

I have checked so many times: Still getting error like `UTIL could not found`.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR should be referenced in Artifactory by a GAV (Group Artifact Version)

You can see the [Gradle dependency declaration in Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/download/attachments/46107965/GradleDependencyDeclaration.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1436781406000&api=v2)

[image: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/download/attachments/46107965/GradleDependencyDeclaration.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1436781406000&api=v2]

Try and copy that in your gradle script.

---

[Adrian M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4084636/adrian-m) point out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56511811/cant-take-jar-from-artifactory/56512054?noredirect=1#comment128793637_56512054) to "[`gradle publish` does not include dependencies in pom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486292/6309)", adding a missing `from components.java` in

```java
publishing {
    publications {
        jar(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/${artifactId}-${libraryVersion}.jar")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't able to see any GAV for the Jars in this Repository.......please help me to find out.

Comment: @prameelab Then can you uoload your JAR to your Artifactory again, but this time as a Maven artifact? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts#DeployingArtifacts-DeployingMavenArtifacts. You will set a GAV then.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me, and I refreshed dependencies.

Comment: @AdrianM. Can you ask a separate question, illustrating "chat does not work for you"? (in your specific context/use case)

Comment: I found the solution needed to publish the jar through gradle with the necessary metadata, etc., that would allow the typical ‘implementation’ declaration for download from the repo.  I could link here, as it‘s an SO Q.

Comment: @AdrianM. Sure, what is the link? I will add it to the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39486292.  Using gradle 6.8 here.

Comment: @AdrianM. Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment and reference in the answer for more visibility.